# mySQL GROUP_CONCAT different Separator each x results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat, separator

in mySQL query is an

```
GROUP_CONCAT(fieldname SEPARATOR ', ')
```

But field with should not be too long. 
Therefore I want a different Separator after x datasets (i.e. each 3rd separator should be '\n')

I would be happy to get help for this.
Thanks!

Comment: You can use ROW_NUMBER() / 3 and then group by this field. See this page for similar examples: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/

Answer (score 0):

This is a real pain.  One method uses `lead()` to bring three values together and then filter the values to every third one:

```
select x,
       group_concat(col_3 separator '; ')
from (select t.x,
             concat_ws(', ',
                       col,
                       lead(col, 1) over (order by ?),
                       lead(col, 2) over (order by ?)
                      ) as col_3
             row_number() over (partition by x order by ?) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where mod(seqnum, 3) = 1
group by x;
```

If you want other aggregations, you can filter in the `group_concat()` instead:

```
select x,
       group_concat(case when mod(seqnum, 3) = 1 then col_3 end separator '; ')
```

Comment: Your 2nd proposal sounds good and easy.
BUT is there also an else possible within GROUP_CONCAT
(Separator ususally should be comma but '\n' every 3rd dataset.)

Comment: @Ralph . . . No.  The second solution *is* the first solution; it just removes the `where` clause.  I think that is clear in the answer.